# Swagger UI "Try it out" option for my DotNet Core 6 API does not work with Azure Kubernetes Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, .net-core, swagger, azure-aks

Swagger UI "Try It Out" option for DotNet Core 6 API app does not work with nginx ingress in azure kubernetes service (aks) , the path for service does not get added in the URL . I have tried multiple options like adding swagger endpoint in program.cs or removing the target-rewrite option but nothing worked.

The swagger UI works fine with localhost and with LoadBalancer service but not with nginx controller as shown below:

[image]

Below is my Ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /serv1/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp
            port:
              number: 80
```

Below is how my "program.cs" file looks

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
    
//     options =>
// {
//     options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
//     //options.RoutePrefix = "serv1/swagger";
// });


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Have you tried with the commented part code ?

Comment: yes but that gives error like swagger.json not found

Comment: The path may be wrong.Try with `.`.Options.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json and check once.

Comment: Tried that as well when I try "./swagger/v1/swagger.json" it takes literally the "." as well and ends up in same error

Comment: Try this once..services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
        c.SwaggerDoc("swagger/v1", new OpenApiInfo { Version = "1.0", Title = "API" });
    );

Comment: Are you getting the same 404 error when accessing the url directly in the browser ?

Comment: No when I try with postman it works fine as I add the path in url which the try it out option is omitting "http://20.237.82.31/serv1/WeatherForecast"